# regex for calculating unique ID's in awk

Tags: awk

My requirement is to get the count of items that are unique. I have a file like the below

Input file

```
ID1=7
ID1=5 
ID1=5 
ID1=6
ID1=6
```

basically I will be using reg ex for searching the word ID, I would give like "ID=*"...

My output should be

```
Count of unique  ID1=2
```

Could you please help me guys ...Thank you.

Comment: Given your sample data, wouldn't the output be `Count of unique ID=5`? Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk -F= '{if (!($1 SUBSEP $2 in a)) {ids[$1]++; a[$1, $2]}} END {for (id in ids) {print "Count of unique", id, " " ids[id]}}'
```

Using this input:

```
ID1=7
ID1=5
ID1=5
ID1=6
ID1=6
ID2=4
ID2=3
ID1=5
ID3=4
ID2=3
```

This is the output:

```
Count of unique ID1  3
Count of unique ID2  2
Count of unique ID3  1
```

Comment: I just want to know the meaning of this statement $1 SUBSEP $2... Which one are you referring as $1 and $2.. It would be highly helpful if I get this info .. Thank you

Comment: @User: Together, `$1 SUBSEP $2` is the index into the array `a` and corresponds to `a[$1, $2]`. `SUBSEP` is a special variable AWK uses to separate parts of a simulated multidimensional array subscript. In this case, the two parts consist of `$1` (the part before the `=` because of the `FS` being set to `=` with `-F=`) and `$2` (the part after the `=`). The statement `if (!($1 SUBSEP $2 in a))` means "if the subscript `[$1, $2]` exists in the array `a`... The value of `SUBSEP` defaults to `\034`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    { ++counts[$0];  }

END { 
    for (i in counts)
        printf("Count of unique %s = %d\n", i, counts[i]); 
}
```

Comment: can $1 and $2 be used to refer the first and second field of a variable .. Such that if session=5 is stored in a variable. Then I would like to have $1 referring to session and $2 to 5 . Thank you

Comment: It can, but it's not entirely trivial -- fields are separated by the the field separator, which defaults to whitespace. You can change that with `FS="Whatever";` in the program or `-F"Whatever"` on the command line.

Comment: So if the variable is name="session,5" can I use FS=name and refer $1 which is the first field of name

Comment: @User: i'm not quite sure what you're asking. If you have input of `session,5` and want to split it at the comma, then `FS=",";` would let you do that. If the data is already in a variable, then you'd normally use `split` instead.